# Why 2d dynamic array has initial values?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization, new-operator

I'm trying to use the new operator to allocate a 2d array. This is my function new2d.

```
int** new2d(int r, int c)
{
    int **t = new int*[r];
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        t[i] = new int[c];
    return t;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is the correct way to do it. However, when I try to print the array like below

```
int **a = new2d(5, 9);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

it gives this weird output with random 13,10,7...

```
0 0 0 0 13 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You never initialized the values in each row. The data you see is *indeterminate*. Change this: `new int[c];` to this: `new int[c]();`. Better still, change the whole thing to `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(5, std::vector<int>(9));`

Comment: It is well known that `new` is not required to initialise the allocated memory for you. If it were, and you wanted something other than its default initialisation, `new` would be making a decision for you, only to waste your time. However, by deliberately specifying a constructor on the target object, you can have _it_ perform its own defined initialisation.

Comment: I highly recommend doing as WhozCraig says. Playing with raw pointers is risky.

Comment: ^ Especially when C++ offers so many better solutions.

Comment: Got it, thanks guys! But what's the new int[c]( ); for?

Comment: `()` invokes the default ctor for `int`, which conveniently initialises to 0.

Comment: @TonyTarng it invokes *value-initialization*, and is covered in the standard, C++11 § 8.5,p7, and C++11 § 8.5,p10. After going on about discussion various construction models, the bailout case is simply "... otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized**." Worth reading. Get a copy.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default initialization can lead to indeterminate values. Quoting from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

> Default initialization is performed in three situations:
>
> 1) when a variable with automatic, static, or thread-local storage duration is declared with no initializer.
>
> 2) when an object with dynamic storage duration is created by a new-expression with no initializer or when an object is created by a new-expression with the initializer consisting of an empty pair of parentheses (until C++03).
>
> 3) when a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in a constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.
>
> The effects of default initialization are:
>
> If T is a non-POD (until C++11) class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty argument list.
>
> The constructor selected (which is one of the default constructors) is called to provide the initial value for the new object.
>
> If T is an array type, every element of the array is default-initialized.
>   Otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.

In your case, you meet condition 2.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not initialize array after `t[i] = new int[c];`
However this is not optimal way to create arrays. Here is a bigger discussion
[How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Well. Usually it is better to use an approach such as

```
int *array = new int[sizeX*sizeY];
```

`ary[i][j]` is then rewritten as `array[i*sizeY+j]`.

And yes, it is better to read big discussion, to understand + and - better

Comment: Saying "this is not optimal" implies there is a better way. Linking to a large discussion of several alternative methods does not tell us _which_ way you think is better. This does not help much.